# Plotting each tickline with individually specified color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, subplot, xticks

I am trying to change the color of the ticklines in my plot, where I would like to assign the colors based on a list of strings with color codes. I am following the following approach, but I cannot see why that does not work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.tan(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y']
ax1.set_xticks(x)
for tick, tickcolor in zip(ax1.get_xticklines(), colors):
    tick._color = tickcolor
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know the correct implementation of this?

Comment: Maybe related [`GH25522`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25522).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, `tick._color`/`tick.set_color(tickcolor)` isn't working due to a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25522):

Using `tick.set_markeredgecolor` is the workaround, but it doesn't seem to be the only issue. `ax1.get_xticklines()` yields the actual ticks lines on every two items, you should thus only `zip` those:

```
for tick, tickcolor in zip(ax1.get_xticklines()[::2], colors):
    tick.set_markeredgecolor(tickcolor)
```

Output:

[image]

*NB. also changing the ticks width for better visualization of the colors.*

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.tan(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y']
ax1.set_xticks(x)
for tick, tickcolor in zip(ax1.get_xticklines()[::2], colors):
    tick.set_markeredgecolor(tickcolor)
    tick.set_markeredgewidth(4)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One sketchy way is this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.tan(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y']
ax1.set_xticks(x)
for tick, tickcolor in zip(ax1.xaxis.majorTicks, colors):
    tick._apply_params(color=tickcolor)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I believe it is sketchy because I'm relying on a "private" method (whose name starts with *underscore*).